# Class with for Canvas and a method for painting - Java

Tags: java, swing, class, canvas, methods

I have the following problem:
I created this class in Java:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class OvalPanelCanvas extends JPanel {
public OvalPanelCanvas() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Oval Sample");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(this);
    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g, int a, int b) {

g.setColor(Color.black);
g.drawLine(10, 10, a, b);
}
public static  void main(String args[]) {



}
}
```

The method paintComponent(Graphics g, int a, int b) is called by a function from another class:

```
testen.paintComponent(f,50, 50);
```

f is a Graphics object created as public. When the other Class starts the JFrame of the OvalPanelVanvas Class starts, but it doesn't draw when the method is called?
I'm now thinking why, because there is no Error message.

Comment: What about repaint() hav eyou tried that?

Comment: the function, which calles the method is called every time when i press a button, so I think it is also okay to press the button more times? 
Also no effect!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a wierd/obscure/just plan wrong understanding of how custom painting works. Honestly I don't even know where to begin, there's so many things that just look plain wrong.

- You're not correctly override `paintComponent`. The correct signature is

  ```
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  ```

  with *no* other arguments.
- **You should never create the `JFrame` in the `JPanel` constructor.** Do it in the `main` method or a method that you call in the `main` method, like a commonly used `createAndShowGui()`
- You should be calling `super.paintComponent` inside the `paintComponent` method.
- If you do want to repeatedly repaint as mentioned in your comment, call `repaint()` and not the `paintComponent` method explicitly, which you should never have to do. It is called implicitly through the paint stack.
- If you wanted to change the `a` and `b` values, what you should do is have them as class members `int a, b` and setters for them. Like

  ```
  public class OvalCanvasPanel extends JPanel {
      int a, b;
      public OvalCanvasPanel(int a, int b) {
          this.a = a;
          this.b = b;
      }
      @Override
      protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
          super.paintComponent(g);
          g.fillOval(10, 10, a, b);
      }
      public void setA(int a) {
          this.a = a;
          repaint();
      }
  }
  ```

  Then from the class you instantiate the `OvalCanvasPanel`, you can just set the `a` and `b`, and it will `repaint()`
- `frame.add(this);` NO!. Should be `frame.add(new OvalCanvasPanel());`

---

I suggest you go over [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) to see some examples, good practices, and correct ways to paint.

Comment: @dic19 NO, Good catch on _your_ part! I totally overlooked that. I just assumed it was an oval when I was typing my answer, because I only remembered seeing two args when I skimmed through it ;)

Comment: Haha lol! But that makes sense anyway because of the class name: `OvalCanvasPanel`. After I saw your `paintComponent` implementation I thought to myself: "He's right, if the class name contains Oval word then drawing a plain line doesn't make sense".

Answer (score 1):

Some notes:

- First of all you should override `paintComponent()` method. Don't
  forget to call `super.paintComponent(g)`.
- Give your class setters to `a` and `b` attributes and call [repaint()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29) method from the outside.
- Take a look to [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) tutorial.
- Don't set the frame's size (or any Swing components size actually) . You can give a default size to the panel by overriding [getPreferredSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getPreferredSize%28%29) method.

#### Example:

```
public class OvalPanelCanvas extends JPanel {

    private int a, b;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D)g.create(); // just as good practice
        graphics.setColor(Color.black);
        graphics.drawLine(10, 10, a, b);
        graphics.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return isPreferredSizeSet() ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void setB(int b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly I just threw a bunch of stuff out there. I have absolutely no clue what the OP is trying to achieve lol

Comment: Honestly... me too :P I *guess* OP is trying to learn about custom painting in swing. However his/her class constructor doesn`t make sense and it's really confusing. Also class name doesn't make sense since OP's code just draw a line (or tries to do so). @peeskillet

Answer (score 0):

It must not call directly to `paintComponent()` and it must not directly create a `Graphics` object. `Graphics` object is a painting context created by system, so you only have to add your OvalPanelCanvas object to the frame and system call `paintComponent()` automatically when is needed.